# MongoDB - how to reference children/nested document _id's within parent on insert

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am very new to MongoDb but the project I was just brought in on uses it to store message threads like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("messageThreadId"),
    "messages": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("messageId"),
            "body": "Lorem ipsum..."
        }, etc...]
    "users": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("userId"),
            "unreadMessages": ['messageId', 'messageId', etc...]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to use pymongo to insert brand new `messageThread`s which should (initially) contain a single message. However, I am not clear on how to construct the `users.unreadMessages` lists of `messageId`s (which should contain just the newly-created initial message). Is there a way of referencing the initial message's `_id` before/as it's created, from within the same document? Also worth noting that `unreadMessages` is a list of strings, not `ObjectId()`s.

Do I need to create the `messageThread` with the `unreadMessages` list empty, then go back and retrieve the initial message's `_id` that was just created, then update every `unreadMessages` in the list of users? It feels wrong to require multiple transactions for an insert, but this whole schema feels wrong to me.

Comment: You can create an ObjectId() with `var_name = ObjectId()`. You can also cast it to a string with `str_name = str(var_name)`, then use the variable instead of generating the ObjectId at insert time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DaveStSomeWhere said, I ended up pre-generating the `ObjectId` and then using it in the document before insertion. This is what PyMongo does when it goes to insert a document anyways: [the relevant code in `pymongo.collection.insert_one()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qNYw.png). Thanks Dave.